# HTML - Allow only pattern with numbers and dots for input type text

Tags: html, regex

I need to have a text input that accepts only numbers and the dot sign for float numbers.

I don't want a number type input.

Comment: How is your current RegEx ? Why don't you want to use input type number ?

Comment: I didn't downvote your question, but that's like *"Let's ask before searching"*

Comment: Here's what I typed : "HTML pattern how to allow only numbers and dots", and here I am with no answer from Google ;) well anyway, I got my answer here, thanks

Comment: You could have typed *"regex float number"*

Answer (score -2):

You can't do this with html only - you'd need to use JavaScript.

e.g. [Javascript key board input filtering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009426/javascript-key-board-input-filtering)

There is an `<input pattern="">` attribute which can be used for validation, but it does not prevent the input from accepting invalid characters, only prevents them being submitted when the form is validated.

Comment: [The `pattern` attribute of `input` elements accepts regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#htmlattrdefpattern)

Comment: Oh wow, you're quite correct. It's well supported too - https://caniuse.com/#feat=input-pattern

Comment: @VLAZ Having just tested this it doesn't prevent the input accepting things which don't match the pattern. It's only used for validation when the form is submitted. I therefore stand by my original answer - this requires javascript.